# Connection reset by peer (502) in RESTful Web Service

Tags: .net, wcf, connection, reset

I have a RESTful WCF service (.NET 3.5), which has a function that is supposed to return a list of patient details by matching with the search criteria I have provided. I am facing a issue, wherein if I provide a search criteria that returns one patient detail it works fine; but when I provide a search criteria that returns multiple patient details, I get an error "Connection reset by peer 502".I am using Fiddler to test it since request and response are both in JSON format.

The following is the error I get :

```
<HEAD><TITLE>Connection reset by peer</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Connection reset by peer</H1><HR>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Connection reset by peer</B></FONT>
<HR>
<!-- default "Connection reset by peer" response (502) -->
</BODY>
```

I am pretty sure it was working fine at one point of time when it returned two set of patient details, but it suddenly stopped working without any good reason. And I have enabled Application Logs using health monitoring, it shows application started and no error as such. The other function, which is a "login" function works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem. I had `IsRequired` set to `true` in the Response class of `Data Member`, which was giving the error

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about the solution but sometimes WCF serialization errors may leave you a "connection reset by peer" if you have a DataContract that includes a type that is non serializable. Check if all your types in the datacontract are serializable.

Comment: Thanks, although I didn't find any serialization issues; while having a look at the Data Contract part I found the response classes had Is Required set to false. I just removed those attributes and the problem seems to have vanished!